# CURLOPT_HEADER returns 401

Tags: php, curl

I need to get the location header. From what I've read, this should be as simple as

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
```

If I don't include those two options, the curl request works fine, but I'm not able to get the location header.

If I do include those two options, then I get a 401 error.

The Location that is being returned should be a URL that does require an additional login. What am I doing wrong?

If it makes a difference, I'm doing a PUT.

Update: 
Turns out I was looking too much at the trees and not enough at the forest. When generated the information needed for a response to this question I realized the issue was actually with the call prior to this call.

Before the PUT, I need to get a session token. Since I wasn't parsing out the headers when getting the session token, I was getting a blank session token which was resulting in the 401 for the PUT.

Comment: Response headers are **included** to the result of `curl_exec` when you set `CURLOPT_HEADER` option. So if you want to get some response header you have to extract it from the result using `substr()' and `curl_getinfo(CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)`

Comment: 10.4.2 *401 Unauthorized - The request requires user authentication*. [Reference](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP response headers are **included** to the result of `curl_exec` when you set `CURLOPT_HEADER` option. So if you want to get response headers you have to extract it from the result using `substr()` and `curl_getinfo(CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)`.

Here is a sample:

```
$c = curl_init();
// setting options including CURLOPT_HEADER
// ...
$result = curl_exec($c);
$info = curl_getinfo($c);
curl_close($c);
// extracting headers from result:
$n = $info['header_size'];
$headers = rtrim(substr($result, 0, $n));
$content = substr($result, $n);
```

Comment: Yes, but when I dump $result, it's a 401 error if I set CURLOPT_HEADER. If I don't set CURLOPT_HEADER, then the PUT works fine, but since I didn't set CURLOPT_HEADER, the location isn't included.

Comment: You have to provide the full code you use with CURL. Otherwise I can't help you

Comment: Turns out I was looking too much at the trees and not enough at the forest. When generated the information needed for a response to this question I realized the issue was actually with the call prior to this call.

Before the PUT, I need to get a session token. Since I wasn't parsing out the headers when getting the session token, I was getting a blank session token which was resulting in the 401 for the PUT.

Marked this as the answer since the issue was extracting the header. Thanks for the help!